# Magento - What is the internal url for shipping step in onepage checkout?

Tags: magento

I am using an observer to check the shipping information provided by the customer during onepage checkout. By observing the event `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` I want to redirect the customer back to the shipping step to re-enter their information.

Following the conversation on this page, [What is the correct way to stop a checkout from an event observer in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729429/what-is-the-correct-way-to-stop-a-checkout-from-an-event-observer-in-magento), I have everything set up, but I do not want to redirect them to cart, just the shipping step.

`Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('what/goes/here'));`

Can I make the code simply refresh the page?
`Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));` does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

url = `checkout/onepage/shipping_method`

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. That didn't work either. It still redirects to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()) {
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
}
```